# Triggering User Event after creating a record in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite

I could swear this worked a few versions back, but now it doesn't seem to.

My script creats a new Customer record, and I have a User Event (After Submit) deployed on the Customer record.

I've tried setting the record mode to be dynamic - even tried setting the sourcing to true, however, I can't seem to get the User Event to trigger after I create the record.

Here's a sample of what my script looks like, as you can see, it's quite simple:

```
var customerRecord = nlapiCreateRecord("customer", {recordmode: "dynamic"});
customerRecord.setFieldValue("companyname", "test company");

nlapiSubmitRecord(customerRecord, true, false);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the NetSuite Help page titled *What are User Event Scripts?*:

> User event scripts cannot be executed by other user event scripts. You
>   can, however, execute a user event script from a call within a
>   NetSuite scheduled script, a portlet script, or a Suitelet.

I am not sure if this is due to a recent release or not, but this could be why it is no longer working.

Answer (score 2):

Is the script that is creating the Customer record a User Event script also?  If yes, then a User Event script cannot trigger another User Event script.  NetSuite does not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, I am also facing the same problem. 
After so many trials I find out that you cannot trigger user event from another user event. **And 1 more thing**, you can also not trigger any workflow attached to the record from user event.

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger a User Event Script from a user event script, but you can call a Suitelet within your User Event Script that you can use to trigger the other User Event Script to run.

This is shown here: https://videohub.oracle.com/media/SuiteScript+2.0+%26gtB+User+Event+Script+to+Trigger+another+User+Event+Script+using+Suitelet/1_vgt8ud6n